# how to get back to the start of the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get back to the start of the array but it keeps returning the second item in the array.

```
var counter = 0;
var srcArray = ["/images/e2450-1.png", "/images/e2450-2.png", "/images/e2450-3.png"];

function nextFunction() {
    document.getElementById("chat-bubble").src = srcArray[++counter];

    if (counter == 2) {
        counter = 0;
    };
    return srcArray;
}
```

If anybody could help it would be great.

Comment: btw, a block statement needs no semicolon after.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing your `counter` before using it. try `counter++`.

`++counter` increment the counter than evaluate the expression.
`counter++` evaluate the expression then increment the counter.

```
var counter = 0;
var srcArray = ["/images/e2450-1.png", "/images/e2450-2.png", "/images/e2450-3.png"];

function nextFunction() {
    document.getElementById("chat-bubble").src = srcArray[counter++];

    if (counter == 2) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    return srcArray;
}
```

Comment: Now it doesnt get the last item in the array

Comment: then change your condition to `counter == 3` @BobSmith

Answer (score 1):

Array index starts from 0 and not 1. The below change should work

```
document.getElementById("chat-bubble").src = srcArray[counter++];
```

This will set srcArray[0] which is the 1st item in array and then increment the count to 1.